# Ninject UserManager to Controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, ninject

I have this controller:

```
 public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        public UserController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
        }

        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }
        public ActionResult Users()
        {
            var users = UserManager.Users.ToList();
            var usersRoles = new List<UserIndexResponse>();
            foreach (var user in users)

            {
                var roles = UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id);

                var role = roles.FirstOrDefault();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(role))
                {
                    var usersRole = new UserIndexResponse()
                    {
                        Id = user.Id,
                        Email = user.Email,
                        LockedOutDue = user.LockoutEndDateUtc,
                        Role = role
                    };

                    usersRoles.Add(usersRole);
                }

            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

It should just get all users and their roles, and pass the `List<UserIndexResponse>` to the `View`.
When I run it, I get this error:

Error activating IUserStore{ApplicationUser}

No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:

3. Injection of dependency IUserStore{ApplicationUser} into parameter store of constructor of type ApplicationUserManager
4. Injection of dependency ApplicationUserManager into parameter userManager of constructor of type UserController
5. Request for UserController

How do I inject UserManager to UserController?

`ConfigureAuth` code:

```
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });            
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
            // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
            // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

            // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
            //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
            //    clientId: "",
            //    clientSecret: "");

            //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
            //   consumerKey: "",
            //   consumerSecret: "");

            //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            //   appId: "",
            //   appSecret: "");

            //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            //{
            //    ClientId = "",
            //    ClientSecret = ""
            //});
        }
```

`NinjectWebCommon`:

```
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<ICategoryService>().To<CategoryService>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IPostService>().To<PostService>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<ICommentService>().To<CommentService>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IImageService>().To<ImageService>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().To<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
            kernel.Bind<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>().ToSelf();
        }
```

Comment: Probably the problem is not here but in _startup.cs_ or _program.cs_ Are you using AspNetCore MVC or AspNet MVC?

Comment: @Steve AspNet MVC. Can't I just inject it like any other service in `NinjectWebCommon`?

Comment: OK, then you should have the Injection system setup in App_Start\StartupAuth.cs. Please show the code in the ConfigureAuth method from that file.

Comment: Sorry, cannot see any error here. I am not familiar with NinjectWebCommon. I suggest to search for the specific error message.

Comment: @Steve ah ok thanks. Also added the NinjectWebCommon where the bindings are.

Comment: @mason no, still not getting it... Isn't this what you're saying: 
`kernel.Bind<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().To<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();` ?

Comment: Did you include the entire error message? You have bullets points 3, 4, and 5....did you leave out 1 and 2?

Comment: @mason the stackoverflow editor did that. In reality it was 1,2,3

Comment: Is the `UserStore<ApplicationUser>` class yours? If so, what dependencies does it have? Also, where do you invoke the RegisterServices method?

Comment: no, it isnt mine. RegisterServices is inside NinjectWebCommon.cs which is inside the App_Start folder. All other bindings work correctly, except this one.

Comment: You answered where RegisterServices is located, but I'm asking instead where you invoke it. What method invokes it? What invokes that method? Have you set a breakpoint in there and verified that RegisteredServices gets called? What's the stack trace when it hits the breakpoint?

Comment: @mason well when I put a breakpoint on `RegisterServices`, it gets called when I run the program